# Better approach to build graph from list clustering related items by two properties

Tags: python-2.7, graph

I have a list of songs.  For each song I have the artist, writer and genre.

I want to create a directed graph so I can look for patterns.

So, I want to have a node for each artist, and so I will start with clustering the songs based on artist.

Then I want to also find the composer and somehow arrange the already clustered songs so they are close to the writer.

Later I will also group based on genre, but I am stuck on the first two.

So, my first approach is to just do something like (**not tested**):

```
pos_x = 20
for x in songs:
    pos_y = 20
    artist_list = [s for s in songs if s.artist==x.artist]
    for y in len(artist_list):
        artist_list[y].x = pos_x
        pos_x += 10 * len(artist_list[y].title)
        artist_list[y].y = pos_y
        pos_y += 10
```

I would then loop over artist list, create the initial graph, but there is a problem when multiple artists are on one song, such as *We are the world*.

But, I believe in Python this is a horribly flawed approach as my next approach would be to take the songs, keeping them relatively close to the artist, but loop over to get the composer and make small changes to the groups to put those related close together, so the clusters of songs for artists may be moved.

I am using `pyglet` to do this, so basically I am doing this in OpenGL.

The actually positioning I can do, but it is the approach I am concerned about, as I am stuck on how should I approach this problem.

**UPDATE**

What I am looking for is something like:

```
   Song A1          Song A3       Song A2         

                      Artist A     
                                  Artist B

   Song B1                      Song B2
```

I would have lines going from A1,A2,A3 to Artist A, and B1,B2 going to Artist B, but A3 and B1, B2 connected to Artist B, but I also want the placement of Artist B closer to A2 and B2 as these two songs have the same composer.

So the artist will be a new node, separate from the songs, but the actual placement of songs within each cluster will depend on at least one other relationship.  Later I may end up showing that relationship also, which is why I am mapping in 3D at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I would take is to generate a directed graph in Python that can be written into the "dot" format and rendered by Graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org). Graphviz and the dot format are established tools for defining and rendering complex graphs.

The great news is that there are Python libraries that allow you to define the graph in a Pythonic manner, and then write out the dot file with a single line of code. PyGraphviz looks like a good choice: http://networkx.lanl.gov/pygraphviz. You can create the structure of the graph in Python, which is as simple as defining edges between songs and artists, between songs and composers, and so forth. Here's a snippet from the PyGraphviz tutorial:

```
>>> G.add_node('a') # adds node 'a'
>>> G.add_edge('b','c') # adds edge 'b'-'c' (and also nodes 'b', 'c')
```

Then just write the dot file and load it into Graphviz, which will lay out the nodes in 2d space. There are a variety of layout algorithms, so you can experiment with them in order to cluster the songs in the most useful manner.

Comment: I am currently doing it in opengl instead of dot as I am not certain where the project is going, so I am prototyping, and I may end up needing to display in 3D, and it is easier to go from OpenGL -> dot if I decide that will work then to convince others for me to pay a price to go from dot to OpenGL.  My problem is a better way to do the clustering and placement, rather than using for loops.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the difficult part is laying out the nodes in space in a way that best respects the clustering, right? It's a hard problem, and Graphviz implements layout algorithms to do that. You can use PyGraphviz (or perhaps NetworkX, see [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727820/networkx-style-spring-model-layout-for-directed-graphs-in-graphviz-pygraphviz)) to generate the coordinates of each node (`G.layout()`), without actually generating a PDF file, and then you can use those coordinates to draw with OpenGL however you like.

Comment: I will look at these.  Thank you.  Yes, figuring out how to lay them out due to clustering is the challenge, as I may end up needing to take other attributes into account and do more than one pass, but if I can do it for two attributes then doing it for 3 or four will not be much more challenging.

Comment: I still have the same problem, if I use NetworkX, as to I need to determine how they should be placed, from what I am seeing.

Comment: You should only need to define the connections between nodes, and the layout algorithm should come up with positions for you. Have a look at [this simple example](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/weighted_graph.html) — the author merely defines which nodes are connected to each other, calls spring_layout to calculate the node positions, and then draws those positions.